# Django ORM extra info in query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have some models in my Django application like this:

I have a `Post` entity:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....
```

And `LikePost` entity to save the users that has created a Like on a post.

```
class LikePost(models.Model):
    # Author info
    author_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='post_likes')

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="likes")
    dateJoined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to retrieve some Post:

```
Post.objects.filter(....)...
```

but for each Post I need also to know if the current user has already performed a like action on the post.

So, I need to have a query to retrieve the list of post and for each post set info I would to annotate also this extra info (for example an additional field `'liked'= True|False`)

I have to tried something like '`extra`' function but I failed to use this on two model: query on Post and extra info on LikePost.
Is possible this?
Any  examples is welcome!

**-------- EDIT ---------**

***!! I can't change my models configuration !!***

Comment: You should take a look at the [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 1):

I would not separate these two models. Just add new field `liked_by` to Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_posts')
   liked_by = models.ManyToMany(User, related_names='liked_posts')
```

and

```
user_liked_posts = request.user.liked_posts.all()
```

**If you cannot change models, then:**

```
user_liked_posts = request.user.post_likes.select_related('post')
# likes on posts done by request.user
# so "author_user" is request.user  
for like in user_liked_posts:
    like.dateJoined
    like.post.title
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...Yes, This is a good solution but now I can't change my model :( I need to found a good solution for my models configuration as I have explained..

Comment: ok, but my question is different... I would to have this information like extra field in my queryset. Your suggestion is what I have currently implemented. But I would like to have this information (such as a field liked=True|False)  directly in queryset result (Something like .ANNOTATE or .EXTRA for Django ORM)... I would like to use a single query for efficiency reasons.